# use reference variables then they are not parsed yet?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm new to Angular, just a question on the use of reference variables, below is some example code:

```
<div class="bg-info text-white p-2">
   Selected Product: {{product.value || '(None)'}}
</div>
<div class="form-group">
   <label>Product Name</label>
   <input #product class="form-control" (input)="false" />
</div>
```

I acknowledge the fact that #product creates a template reference variable represents input element in the DOM, so that `product` can be used by other bindings which is below that in the same template.

But `product.value` comes before the definition of product  reference variable, which means that when the first div's content is being parsing, `product` hasn't been defined yet so it should not be available to use now, so isn't that `undefined.someProperty` will trigger the 'not defined' reference error?

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. Angular parses the whole template before executing any logic so when it evaluates the binding in `{{product.value || '(None)'}}` the template variable `product` is already defined. It is usually safe to use template variables anywhere in your template.